# AngularJS window.close not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble calling the `window.close` function, without getting the following error:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Here is how I have my app laid out:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="mynewAPP" ng-controller="appCTRL">

....blahblah </html>
```

My Angular controls work fine, but when I call `window.close`, it is not working (at least the closing part... rest of app is fine).

```
app.controller("appCTRL" ,function( [injections]){
  $window.close();
}
```

How would I go about allowing AngularJS to close the window it is sitting on?

For example the below script would work fine: (basic JS)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeme(){
        window.close(); 
    }

    </script></head>

    <body onload="closeme()"></body>
</html>
```

For those that are wondering how I am opening the page, simply by visiting "mypage.html" on the browser. Nothing fancy.

Comment: The important part here is how you've opened the window, as the error message says.

Comment: Just as a new browser (i.e by visiting mypage.html)

Comment: Then you can't close the window programmatically. The "basic JS" version would also not do it.

Comment: yes, this "basic js" does do it, as i have tested it.. in both IE and Chrome (FF doesnt close it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to security restriction you can only close windows with `window.close` that were opened by javascript.

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close)

Comment: look at the bottom of the page though:

Closing the current window

When you call the window object's close() method directly, rather than calling close() on a window instance, the browser will close the frontmost window, whether your script created that window or not.

Comment: That only means that the created window instance can close itself. It will still have to be a window that was created through JavaScript.

Comment: What are you trying to say @nate? What @Juhana said, this doesn't alter the security restrictions.

Comment: So then How can we close window, whether we open new window explicitly or not? Just I want to close opened window.

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq If you didn't open that window, you don't. Otherwise, window.close();